# How to tell what HDMI version my system supports - Ubuntu Linux (10.10)

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi, ubuntu-10.10

Looking to see if the HDMI output of my machine (with an nVIDIA GeForce 460M card) is HDMI 1.3 compatible or not.  Not sure what the command is to tell that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Any given product can choose to implement only a subset of its HDMI version. In what feature are you interested?

Comment: HDMI is a strange spec.  There are certain features that are required for a certain spec, but there are optional features within that spec.

Answer (score -2):

Caveat: The following haven't been tested by me!

Try connecting a monitor/TV to the HDMI output and:

1. See if the [`xrandr`](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR) utility displays the relevant information.
2. Search the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file for all instances of the string "HDMI" (case insensitive of course), then check all the lines in the vicinity. (You might need to copy the file using sudo, change the extension to .txt and also edit the permissions so you can read it.)