# Command to see what version of HDMI

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, hdmi

Is there a windows command to determine which version of HDMI specification is available/implemented on a given video adapter or other HDMI information?

Software utilities are also welcome.

Similar question for Ubuntu [went unanswered here](https://superuser.com/questions/413919/how-to-tell-what-hdmi-version-my-system-supports-ubuntu-linux-10-10)

Comment: I doubt there is a command.  HDMI communication is done through hardware, not software/OS.  The video adapter would have to provide it through its own software.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the wmic commands and did not see anything, maybe a 3rd party utility of some sort?

Comment: Did you see the CIM_VideoControllerResolution class in WMI? In powershell do: Get-WMIObject CIM_VideoControllerResolution

Comment: I was thinking WMIC or Registry, if anything.  Perhaps searching WMIC with PowerShell might help, if it's there.  I agree with @Keltari though, that this is probably not a function that will be built-in to Windows.  If at all, it's probably only available through your device vendor's drivers and/or configuration software.  If you're really lucky, you might be able to dig it up in some vendor-specific Registry key - but this will not likely be a solution that is widely applicable.

Comment: @EBGreen I ran the command you suggested, and that does not appear to have the information Moab is looking for.  It's simply a list of supported screen resolutions, color depths, and refresh rates.  Moab is looking for the supported [HDMI Versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi#Versions).

Comment: There may be other issues too.  I dont know how the HDMI specs work, but I was thinking its possible there could be other issues.  IE, graphics card and receiver might be at 1.3, but the TV and receiver is 1.1.  What would get returned?  Still interesting to see if there is a solution out there.

Comment: I just replied to the other post, but unfortunately it's all pure guess-work at this point till someone can confirm if it works.

Answer (score -2):

What you're trying to accomplish can either be enumerated from the driver files if they're accomodating or from the Registry, but the registry stores it in unfriendly bytes instead of strings.

I used to work in an independent computer store reselling used equipment and we'd use Monitor Asset Manager from Entech to enumerate video cards and monitor EDID info and it would also display HDMI info.
Edid Manager from Extron is another useful GUI utility that would give us more info than any human could possibly want from their video card even from the restricted Properties key in the display devices registry settings that normally require system access to obtain.
Both are shareware and free respectively.

Dumpedid from Nirsoft.net is a good and free command line utility and can also enumerate remote systems and dump into a text result file.

I personally despise WMI since it always seems to give me too much of the useless  info and fails to deliver the right info. If Microsoft could deliver a basic dmesg funcitonality, it would make many people happy.

BUT, for those who are still fascinated by WMI, I've always found Microsofts unsupported WMI code creator (freely downloadable, just google for it) to give more shortcuts on more useless data than you could use.

Comment: Monitor Asset Manager only seems to give me monitor information.

Comment: Neither of these software's reveal any hdmi information for my video controllers, only my monitor.